# How do I delete a div based on what button has been clicked - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number of card divs that represent comments and when the user clicked the delete button on the comment I module pops up asking the user if they are sure they want to delete the comment. I would like the correct comment to be deleted based on which delete button they have clicked.

[image: comments]

[image: module]

Here is my card and module code

```html
<div class="card cardReply">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <img class="youIcon" src="./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png">
         </div>
         
         <div class="col-3">
             <h1 class="cardName">juliusomo</h1>
         </div>

         <div class="col-2 youText">
             <h2 class="you">you</h2>
         </div>

         <div class="col">
             <h2 class="cardDate">2 days ago</h2>
         </div>
     </div>
        <p class="cardComment"><span>@ramsesmiron</span> I couldn't agree more with this. Everything moves so fast and it always seems like everyone knows the newest library/framework. But the fundamentals are what stay constant.</p>
        
        <div class="row">
        
            <div class="col-3 stars">
         
                <img class="stars_plus" src="images/icon-plus.svg" alt="">
                <span class="stars_number">2</span>
                <img class="stars_minus" src="images/icon-minus.svg" alt="">
            </div>
        <div class="col reply d-flex justify-content-end">

            <img class="details_delete_reply" src="images/icon-delete.svg" alt="">
            <button class="details_delete_reply_text" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Delete</button>
            <img class="details_edit_reply" src="images/icon-edit.svg" alt="">
            <span class="details_edit_reply_text">Edit</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="card">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
         <img class="youIcon" src="./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
         <h1 class="cardNameText">amyrobson</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <h2 class="cardDate">1 month ago</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
   <p class="cardComment">Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved. But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.</p>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 stars">
         <img class="stars_plus" src="images/icon-plus.svg" alt="+">
         <span class="stars_number">12</span>
         <img class="stars_minus" src="images/icon-minus.svg" alt="-">
      </div>
      <div class="col reply d-flex justify-content-end">
         <img class="details_edit_reply" src="images/icon-reply.svg" alt="">
         <span class="details_edit_reply_text">Reply</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
         <img class="youIcon" src="./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
         <h1 class="cardNameText">maxblagun</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <h2 class="cardDate">2 weeks ago</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
   <p class="cardComment">Woah, your project looks awesome! How long have you been coding for? I'm still new, but think I want to dive into React as well soon. Perhaps you can give me an insight on where I can learn React? Thanks!</p>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 stars">
         <img class="stars_plus" src="images/icon-plus.svg" alt="+">
         <span class="stars_number">5</span>
         <img class="stars_minus" src="images/icon-minus.svg" alt="-">
      </div>
      <div class="col reply d-flex justify-content-end">
         <img class="details_edit_reply" src="images/icon-reply.svg" alt="">
         <span class="details_edit_reply_text">Reply</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="card">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
         <img class="youIcon" src="./images/avatars/image-amyrobson.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
         <h1 class="cardNameText">amyrobson</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <h2 class="cardDate">1 month ago</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
   <p class="cardComment">Impressive! Though it seems the drag feature could be improved. But overall it looks incredible. You've nailed the design and the responsiveness at various breakpoints works really well.</p>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 stars">
         <img class="stars_plus" src="images/icon-plus.svg" alt="+">
         <span class="stars_number">12</span>
         <img class="stars_minus" src="images/icon-minus.svg" alt="-">
      </div>
      <div class="col reply d-flex justify-content-end">
         <img class="details_edit_reply" src="images/icon-reply.svg" alt="">
         <span class="details_edit_reply_text">Reply</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="card">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
         <img class="youIcon" src="./images/avatars/image-maxblagun.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
         <h1 class="cardNameText">maxblagun</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <h2 class="cardDate">2 weeks ago</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
   <p class="cardComment">Woah, your project looks awesome! How long have you been coding for? I'm still new, but think I want to dive into React as well soon. Perhaps you can give me an insight on where I can learn React? Thanks!</p>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 stars">
         <img class="stars_plus" src="images/icon-plus.svg" alt="+">
         <span class="stars_number">5</span>
         <img class="stars_minus" src="images/icon-minus.svg" alt="-">
      </div>
      <div class="col reply d-flex justify-content-end">
         <img class="details_edit_reply" src="images/icon-reply.svg" alt="">
         <span class="details_edit_reply_text">Reply</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```html
<div class="card cardReply">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
         <img class="youIcon" src="./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
         <h1 class="cardName">juliusomo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 youText">
         <h2 class="you">you</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <h2 class="cardDate">a few seconds ago</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
   <p class="cardComment">hello</p>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 stars">
         <img class="stars_plus" src="images/icon-plus.svg" alt="">
         <span class="stars_number">0</span>
         <img class="stars_minus" src="images/icon-minus.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col reply d-flex justify-content-end">
         <img class="details_delete_reply" src="images/icon-delete.svg" alt="">
         <button class="details_delete_reply_text" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Delete</button>
         <img class="details_edit_reply" src="images/icon-edit.svg" alt="">
         <span class="details_edit_reply_text">Edit</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```html
       <div class="card cardReply">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3">
         <img class="youIcon" src="./images/avatars/image-juliusomo.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-3">
         <h1 class="cardName">juliusomo</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2 youText">
         <h2 class="you">you</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
         <h2 class="cardDate">a few seconds ago</h2>
      </div>
   </div>
   <p class="cardComment">hello</p>
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-3 stars">
         <img class="stars_plus" src="images/icon-plus.svg" alt="">
         <span class="stars_number">0</span>
         <img class="stars_minus" src="images/icon-minus.svg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="col reply d-flex justify-content-end">
         <img class="details_delete_reply" src="images/icon-delete.svg" alt="">
         <button class="details_delete_reply_text" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">Delete</button>
         <img class="details_edit_reply" src="images/icon-edit.svg" alt="">
         <span class="details_edit_reply_text">Edit</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

```html
    <div class="modal fade show" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" style="display: block; padding-left: 0px;" aria-modal="true" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Delete comment</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p class="modal-text">Are you sure you want to delete this comment? This will remove the comment and can't be undone</p>
              <div class="row">
              <div class="col">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-no text-center text-uppercase" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">No, Cancel</button>
              </div>
              <div class="col">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-delete text-center text-uppercase" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" onclick="handleDeleteClick()">Yes, Delete</button>
              </div>
              </div>
            
          </div>
            </div>
          </div>

    </div>
```

Here is the JavaScript that I have tried

```js
const handleDeleteClick = () = \ > {
    const deleteCooment = document.querySelector('.btn-delete')
    const deleteButton = document.querySelector('.details_delete_reply_text');
    deleteCooment.onclick = () = \ > {
        // deleteCooment.target.closest('.card').parentNode.removeChild(deleteCooment.target.closest('.message'));
        console.log("hello");

        deleteButton.forEach(el => {
            el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
                e.target.closest('.card').parentNode.removeChild(deleteCooment.target.closest('.message'));

            });
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The perfect way to deal with the scenario you are dealing with is to understand the basic  way you generate the element else it will be hassle. The fine way to do it is.

```
<div class="comment-wrapper"></div>
```

```
function generateComment(id,commentsData){
//the html comment element
//on deleteButtonClick generateModalFunction(id)
return <div >//the html comment element</div>
}

//for achieving the comments listing
function comments(getcommentsDataArray){
getcommentsDataArray.map((item,index)=>{
   let finalCOmmentElement = generateComment(index,item)
    //push finalCommentElement on the  ".comment-wrapper"
})
}
```

now to achieve the delete

```
generateModalFunction(id){
 return <>return modal code here with onClick(deleteElement(id)) on deletebutton</>
}
```

now remove the elementand regeneratethe comment

```
function deleteElement(id){
let arrayAfterDeletedElement = //getcommentsDataArray remove the element with index id

comments(arrayAfterDeletedElement)

}
```

Comment: I will try and give this a go

Answer (score -1):

How do you store the cards or the data that generates the cards?  You could contain the card data in an array as an array of Card JSON's.  Then you can map the cards out using the array, map the delete function with the card data's index, then remove the data based on the index.

In react it would be something like this, but if its just standard JS you can still do something similar its just a bit more involved.

I.e

Card Render Component

```
const cardData = [{dataSet1}, {dataSet2}, ...]

const delete = (index) => {
  //Method to delete from cardData
}

const renderCards = () => {
  return cardData.map((data, index) => {
  return <Card {...data} delete={()=>delete(index)} />
})
}
```

Card

```
const Card = (..., delete) => {
  return <>
  ...
  <Button onClick={delete} >
</>
}
```

Comment: the information is stored in JSON format which I get using javascript